# PHP: Storing callback functions with arguments on array

Tags: php

I am writing a simple router class which would allow you to execute a function when a route match is found. So, when you are defining routes, you would do something like this:

```
$message = 'Good morning!';

$router->addRoute('GET', 'welcome', function($message) {
    echo $message;
});
```

Then, in the router class, this gets added to an array like:

```
public function addRoute($method, $pattern, $handler) {
    $this->routes[$pattern] = ['method' => $method, 'handler' => $handler];
}
```

Once a match is found by comparing the pattern with the requested URL, I have:

```
return call_user_func($setting['handler']);
```

This gives me an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function`

...so I tried using:

```
return call_user_func_array($setting['handler'], array($message));
```

...but this gives me: `Notice: Undefined variable: message`

How can I pass a function (including arguments, if existing) to execute within the router class using values stored on an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to pass `$message` as an argument *at call time*, it should not be in the function parameter list. You're probably just looking to `use` the variable from the surrounding scope:

```
$message = 'Good morning!';

$router->addRoute('GET', 'welcome', function () use ($message) {
    echo $message;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, do you see any more efficient way of accomplishing this, or does this look like the way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: For including a variable from the surrounding scope in an anonymous function, this is it. There may or may not be other ways of solving whatever larger picture task you're trying to accomplish of course…